# A New formula For Generating Pythagorean Triples?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, solution-verification, pythagorean-triples

(The comments and answers, are no longer relevant to this post other than poestasis's answer, they were caused by misinterpretation)

Using a right triangle with side lengths $(a,b,c)$ where $a , b < c$,
I was thinking about how the area of a Pythagorean triple can be found using the Pythagorean triple right before it and I came across something that worked for a large number of Pythagorean triples,  $12r^2 + a_{r - 1}b_{r-1} = a_rb_r$, a recursive formula in terms of inradius($r$). This seemingly generates a sequence of Pythagorean triples that I could not find used in any other formula. Its important to note that $12r^2$ is  twice the area of Pythagorean triples that stem from side lengths $(3,4,5)$. Using this formula we can find the $1st$ term of sets where the inradius of each Pythagorean triple is $r + r^2k$ ($k$ represents the $k$th term of a sequence) and the relationship between the side lengths are still defined by our recursive formula.

These $1st$ terms are triplets with an even value of $a$ where $r$ increases by $1$:

$(8,15,17),(12,35,37),(16,63,65)...$

Note: We find this using $(8,15,17)$ as we have a recursive formula as well as the knowledge that $r = \frac{a + b - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}2$,  which lets us find the side lengths of each Pythagorean triple.

Here is a sample of what they generate:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
set_1&15,8,17&33,56,65&51,140,149&69,260,269 \\ \hline
set_2&35,12,37&85,132,157&135,352,377&185,672,697 \\ \hline
set_3 &63,16,65&161,240,289&259,660,709&357,1276,1325& \\ \hline
set_4&99,20,101&261,380,461&423,1064,1145&585,2072,2153  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I couldn't seem to find any similar formulas to this one or any method of generating Pythagorean triples that follow this sequence, I am looking for a proof.

Comment: The recursive formula is unclear, the start is for $r=1$?  initiale terms?

Comment: sorry about that, the start for the recursive formula is r = 3,  as $(8 ,15,17)$ has an inradius of $3$.

Comment: $$15=4^2-12,8=2\cdot4\cdot1,17=4^2+1^2$$
$$259=22^2-15^2,660=2\cdot22\cdot15,709=22^2+15^2$$
$$\cdots$$
All your triples are found by the classical formula, so what ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I'm not sure what you mean by that, could you please expand?

Comment: Where is the "new set" ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Sorry, is there a formula that produces these sets? I do not know much about Pythagorean triples could you provide a reference?

Comment: Web search is your friend.

Comment: All primitive Pythagorean triples can be found as $a=r^2-s^2$, $y=2rs$, $z=r^2+s^2$, where $r$ and $s$ are arbitrary integers of opposite parity, $r\gt s\gt 0$, $\gcd(r,s)=1$. This is well known. For example, Theorem 5.5 in Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery's *An Intorduction to the Theory of Numbers*, 5th edition. There is no "new" set of Pythagorean triples. And this is just one known way of ennumerating all primitive Pythagorean triples.

Comment: @poetasis, It is able to obtain all of k =1 and set 1 and set 2 if you include that the odd values of a will produce the inradius of triplets with an odd a starting with (5,12,13).

Comment: If you change the question so that the existing answers are no longer applicable, perhaps it would be better to post a new question. People don't enjoy having their efforts minimized.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see why you said that my answer was no longer relevant. I had shown why $ab-12r^2$ is the product of two legs for another Pythagorean triangle. In any case, I have added a bit to that and included a section on generating the sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generating the Sets**

Given the sets in the question, we can match each triple to one generated by the classical formula: $\left(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2\right)$ where $(m,n)=1$, $2\not\mid m-n\gt0$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c} 
\text{set}_0&3,4,5&5,12,13&7,24,25&9,40,41\\\hline
m,n&2,1&3,2&4,3&5,4\\\hline\text{set}_1&15,8,17&33,56,65&51,140,149&69,260,269\\\hline
m,n&4,1&7,4&10,7&13,10\\\hline
\text{set}_2&35,12,37&85,132,157&135,352,377&185,672,697\\\hline
m,n&6,1&11,6&16,11&21,16\\\hline
\text{set}_3 &63,16,65&161,240,289&259,660,709&357,1276,1325\\\hline
m,n&8,1&15,8&22,15&29,22\\\hline
\text{set}_4&99,20,101&261,380,461&423,1064,1145&585,2072,2153\\\hline
m,n&10,1&19,10&28,19&37,28\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Noticing the pattern in the table above, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\text{column $j$ of set}_k&=\left(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2\right)\\
\text{where }(m,n)&=(1+(2k+1)(j+1),1+(2k+1)j)
\end{align}
$$
Column $0$ is the leftmost column of the table.

To see that $(m,n)=1$, note that $n(j+1)-mj=1$
To see that $2\not\mid m-n\gt0$, note that $m-n=2k+1$

I have added $\text{set}_0$ to the table, following the pattern in the subsequent sets.

These sets do not cover all of the Pythagorean Triples. For example, $(21,20,29)$ is not covered in any of these sets.

---

**Original Answer: Why $\boldsymbol{ab-12r^2=a'b'}$**

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423230), and probably many others, shows the following: all relatively prime Pythagorean triples can be written as $\left\{m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2\right\}$ where $(m,n)=1,\ 2\nmid m-n\gt0$.

The area of a triangle is the inradius times the semi-perimeter. Since a Pythagorean triangle is a right triangle, the area is half the product of the legs. Thus, the inradius is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{inradius}
&=\frac{\text{area}}{\text{semi-perimeter}}\\
&=\frac{mn\left(m^2-n^2\right)}{m^2+mn}\\[9pt]
&=n(m-n)
\end{align}
$$
Suppose that $\{a,b,c\}=\left\{m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2\right\}$ is a Pythagorean triple. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{2mn\left(m^2-n^2\right)}^{\large ab}-12\overbrace{n^2(m-n)^2}^{\large r^2}
&=2m(m+n)n(m-n)-12n(m-n)n(m-n)\\
&=2n(m-n)(m(m+n)-6n(m-n))\\
&=2n(m-n)\left(m^2-5mn+6n^2\right)\\
&=2n(m-n)(m-2n)(m-3n)\\
&=\underbrace{2n(m-2n)\vphantom{\left(n^2\right)}}_{\large e}\underbrace{\left((m-2n)^2-n^2\right)}_{\large d}
\end{align}
$$
where $\{d,e,f\}=\left\{(m-2n)^2-n^2,2n(m-2n),(m-2n)^2+n^2\right\}$ is another Pythagorean triple.

In fact:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-2&2\\
2&1&-2\\
-2&-2&3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
$$
and, inversely,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&2&2\\
-2&1&2\\
-2&2&3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that $d,e,f$ have the same parity as $a,b,c$, respectively.

Because
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-2&2\\
2&1&-2\\
-2&-2&3
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-2&2\\
2&1&-2\\
-2&-2&3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we have $d^2+e^2-f^2=a^2+b^2-c^2$.

Furthermore, as mentioned above,
$$
\begin{align}
\text{inradius}
&=\frac{\text{area}}{\text{semi-perimeter}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{ab}{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
&=\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Connecting Pythagorean triples by inradius is well-known (though kudos to you for finding it on your own!). For example, see [this document by Neville Robbins](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/44-4/quartRobbins04_2006.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is interesting but generates only about $1/3$ of the primitive triples that exist. More complete is the subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C) =(2x-1)^2, x\in\mathbb{N}.\quad$ This subset includes no trivial triples, all primitives triples, and only about $1/3$ of the non-primitives as Euclid's formula. Here is a sample, showing how your formula generates only $Set_2$ and above and only columns $1,4,7,10,\cdots$:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61  \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125  \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169  \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221  \\ \hline
Set_{6} &43,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281   \\ \hline
\end{array}

These are generate by the formula::
\begin{align*}
  A=(2n-1)^2+       & 2(2n-1)k      \\ 
  B=  \qquad\quad\quad   & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\ 
  C=(2n-1)^2+       & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\
\end{align*}

and is equivalent to Euclid's formula with the following substitutions:
$A=(2n-1+k)^2-k^2\quad B=2(2n-1+k)k\quad C=(2n-1+k)^2+k^2$

Is there a way that your formula can generated the missing primitives?