# Is there a tree of Pythagorean quadruples?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trees, pythagorean-triples

It is well-known that there is a trinary tree that contains every primitive Pythagorean triple exactly once. It even has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples).

Is there a similar tree that contains each primitive Pythagorean *quadruple* exactly once?

Comment: It even has a [math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127199/242), with more math the the Wikipedia page. See the paper by  see Cass & Arpaia cited there for that and higher degree forms. Always search first before posting questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that answer! I did search, but clearly not widely enough.

Comment: The tree never made sense to me but some quadruples you might play with are

$$(3,4,12,13)\qquad 
(5,12,84,85)\qquad 
(7,25,312,313)\qquad 
(9,40,840,841)\\ 
(11,60,1860,1861)\quad 
(13,84,132,157)\quad 
(15,8,144,145)\quad 
(15,112,6384,6385)\\
(17,144,408,433)\quad 
(19,180,16380,16381)\quad 
(21,20,420,421)\quad 
(21,220,60,229)\\ $$

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer in the following paper:
[http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/u73/u73.pdf](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/u73/u73.pdf)