# Difficult Complex Number Proof. Given $|w| =1$ or $|v|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, irrational-numbers

> Let $z, w$ be distinct complex numbers. Show that if $|z| = 1$ or $|w| = 1$,
>   then
>
> $$\left|\frac{w-z}{1-\overline{w}z}\right| = 1$$
>
> **Hint:** Note that $|a|^2 = a\overline a$

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and cant seem to find somewhere to start.

Edit: The question linked is a different question

Edit: I have been able to prove the |w|=1 case, but when proving the z case I take these steps and cant seem to figure out where to go next.
$|1-\overline{w}z| = |z\overline{z} - \overline{w}z| = |z||\overline{z} - \overline{w}| = |\overline{z} - \overline{w}|$

Comment: Hint: assume $|z|=1$, so you can write $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in \mathbb R $.

Comment: Somebody down-voted this question.  Why? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Maybe because a little research would [find existing answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/191453/147263) on this very site, not to mention elsewhere.

Comment: "Maybe."  We shouldn't have to take "maybe" for an answer. Whoever down-voted it should explain their objections here in the comments. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was not the first to downvote, but I have just done so now for the reason of lack of *shown* research effort.  This is in line with the tooltip that appears on hovering over the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can suppose that $|w| = 1$ (the problem is equivalent if $|z| = 1$).
$$|1 - \overline{w}z| = \left|1 - \frac zw\right| = \frac1{|w|} |w - z| = |w - z| $$

Comment: I get the w direction pretty well and most of the z direction, but I have gotten to a point where I am getting $|\overline{z}-\overline{w}|$ and don't know how to simplify this to $|w-z|$. Is there a theorem or anything that could explain if this is possible?

Comment: The absolute value of a complex number doesn't change if you take the opposite or the conjugate so $|\overline{z}-\overline{w}| = |z-w| = |w-z|$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we know that $z$ and $w$ are distinct and so 
$$\left|\frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}\right|\neq 0,$$
right?
So try proof by contradiction and remember how norms work with division:
$$\left|\frac ab\right|=|a||b|$$. Note that the only positive real number
that squares to $1$ is $1$.

Comment: that should be $|a|/|b|$