# For which $n$ are there primitive Pythagorean triples with legs of lengths $a$ and $a+n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, triangles, pythagorean-triples

For which n can $a^{2}+(a+n)^{2}=c^{2}$ be solved, where $a,b,c,n$ are positive integers? 
I have found solutions for $n=1,7,17,23,31,41,47,79,89$ and for multiples of $7,17,23$...
Are there infinitely many prime $n$ for which it is solvable?

Comment: The title says "primitive", so $GCD(a,n,c)=1$ is assumed?

Comment: @Angela: Very interesting question!

Comment: A paper with some useful info about this question is Delano Wegener. Primitive Pythagorean triples with sum or difference of legs equal to a prime. Wegener proves that your equation is solvable for prime $p$ iff $p=\pm1\mod 8$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general primitive solution to $x^2+y^2 = z^2$ is given by: $x=u^2-v^2$, $y=2uv$, $z=u^2+v^2$, with $u,v$ relatively prime and not both odd.

For $(a,a+n,z)$ to be a primitive triple, we'd have to have a $(u,v)$ such that: $|u^2 - v^2 - 2uv| = n$.  We can rewrite that as: $(u-v)^2 - 2v^2 = \pm n$

So, setting $w = u-v$, we want to find $(w,v)$ which are relatively prime and $w$ is odd, with:

$$w^2-2v^2 = \pm n$$

This means that $n$ must be odd.

In fact, we can use unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ to show that $n$ can be any product of primes of the form $8k\pm 1$.  Since there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k\pm 1$, the answer to your question is, "yes."

(Oh, and once you find one solution $(w,v)$ for a particular $n$, you can find infinitely many solutions for that $n$.)

Comment: For example, $-71 = w^2 - 2v^2$ has solution $(w,v)=(1,6)$.  So $u=7$, $x=u^2-v^2 = 13$, $y=2uv=84$, and $z=u^2+v^2=85$, so $n=71$ has a solution with $a=13$.

Comment: Explicitly, if $p^2 + (p+n)^2 = r^2$, then subsequent ones can be found as $q^2 + (q+n)^2 = (p+q+r+n)^2$, where $q = 3p+2r+n$.

Answer (score 1):

$2a^{2}+2na+n^{2}=c^{2}$ --> $a=-\frac{-n+\sqrt{2c^{2}-n^{2}}}{2}$ --> there are solutions iff $x^{2}+n^{2}=2c^{2}$ has solutions --> find the set of the squares of all integers 0 in the set such that $y=2x-n$ then there is a primitive pythagorean triple with a difference of n between legs, and also for any multiple An if n>1 since if $k^{2}\equiv x(\mod{n})$ then $(Ak)^{2} \equiv Ax(\mod{An})$ -->  $Ay=2Ax-An$.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many Pythagorean triples where the difference between two legs is either $1$ or any of the infinite prime numbers $P\equiv\pm 1 \mod 8\quad$ taken to any non-zero power.

Under $100\quad 
P\in \{1,7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97\}.\quad $
To find these, we begin with Euclid's formula
$ \quad A=m^2-k^2,\quad B=2mk,\quad C=m^2+k^2\quad$ solve the $\quad (B-A)$ difference equation for $m$ and generate the $(m,k)$ values needed to feed Euclid's formula. Each iteration uses a seed $k$ which is either given or is the $m$-value of the previous iteration. Here is the formula for $P=1$ with a seed $k=1$. Note that $(m,k)$ are Pell numbers.

\begin{equation}
\quad m=k+\sqrt{2k^2+(-1)^k}
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
k=1\space &\implies m=(1+\sqrt{2(1)^2+(-1)^1}\space)\big)=2\quad & F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\
k=2\space  &\implies m=(2+\sqrt{2(2)^2+(-1)^2}\space)\big)=5\quad & F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
k=5\space  &\implies m=(5+\sqrt{2(5)^2+(-1)^5}\space)\big)=12\quad & F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\
k=12\space  &\implies m=(12+\sqrt{2(12)^2 (-1)^{12}}\space)\big)=29\quad  & F(29,12)=(697,696,985)
 \end{align*}

For $P>1$, the formula is
\begin{equation}
 m=k+\sqrt{2k^2\pm P}
 \end{equation}
and there is more than one seed $(s)$ in a set $(k_1)$ each of which generates a subset of the entire set of triples for that difference. There is one more seed than the power $n$ of the prime number that is P. For example, $1$ is a zero power so there is $1$ seed.
$$P=1\implies k_1=\{s1\}=\{1\}\quad 
P=7^1\implies k_1=\{s1,s2\}=\{2,1\}\\ 
P=343=7^3\implies k_1=\{s1,s2,s3, s4\}=\{14,16,3,7\}$$

The elements of $k_1$ are generated as follows.

\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
\text{where}\quad s_i=\sqrt{\frac{j_i^2 + P}{2}}
\\  &\text{for}\space\space\space 1 \le i \le \bigg\lceil\frac{(n+1)}{2}\bigg\rceil \space
  \land \space \space                                      1 \le j_i                \le  \lfloor\sqrt{X}\rfloor\\
\text{where}\space s_i=\sqrt{\frac{j_i^2-P}{2}}
\\ &\text{for}\space    \bigg\lceil\frac{(n+1)}{2}\bigg\rceil + 1 \le i \le (n+1)\space 
  \land \space    \lfloor\sqrt{P} +1 \rfloor \le j_i \le  \lfloor\sqrt{2P}\rfloor
\end{align*}

For example, we have $n=3, P=7^3=343\\$
\begin{align*}
 1 \le   & i \le   2   
 \space             1 \le     & j \le \lfloor\sqrt{343}\rfloor=18
 \space  \\
s_1=\sqrt{\frac{7^2+343}{2}}=14\space\quad  &  s_2=\sqrt{\frac{13^2+343}{2}}=16  \\
3 \le  & i \le  4 
\space  19 \le    &  j  \le \lfloor\sqrt{2(343)}\rfloor=26 
 \space   \\
s_3= \sqrt{\frac{19^2-343}{2}}=3 \quad 
&  s_4=\sqrt{\frac{21^2-343}{2}}=7  \ 
 \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
s_1= 14\quad
     &14+\sqrt{2(14)^2-343}=21\quad   &F(21,14)=(245,588,637)\\
     &21+\sqrt{2(21)^2+343}=56\quad   &F(56,21)=(2695,2352,3577)\\
s_2=16 \quad 
      &16 +\sqrt{2(16)^2-343}=29\quad  &F(29,16)=(585,928,1097)\\
      &29 +\sqrt{2(29)^2-343}=74\quad  &F(74,29)=(4635,4292,6317)\\
s_3=3 \quad 
      &3+\sqrt{2(3)^2+343}=22\quad  &F(22,3)=(475,132,493)\\
      &22+\sqrt{2(22)^2+343}=47\quad  &F(47,22)=(1725,2068,2693)\\
s_4=7 \quad 
      &7 +\sqrt{2(7)^2+343}=28\quad  &F(28,7)=(735,392,833)\\
      &28+\sqrt{2(28)^2+343}=63\quad  &F(63,28)=(3185,3528,4753)\\
 \end{align*}

For $P=1$
These $(m,k)$-values
may be generated directly using a Pell-related equation as follows.
\begin{equation}
 m_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\qquad \qquad\qquad
 k_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}
 \end{equation}
For example

{\small
\begin{align*}
\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{2} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}=2 \quad 
     \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^1 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^1}{2\sqrt{2}}=1 \quad&  F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\    
 \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{3} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}=5 \quad 
     \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^2}{2\sqrt{2}}=2 \quad&  F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{4} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{4}}{2\sqrt{2}}=12 \quad  
      \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^3 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^3}{2\sqrt{2}}=5 \quad& F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\ 
\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{5} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}=29 \quad 
     \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^4 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^4}{2\sqrt{2}}=12 \quad& F(29,12)=(697,696,985)
 \end{align*}
}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/k2k12-being-a-perfect-square-for-infinitely-many-k/700126#700126   there's a connection to Pell's equation.

Comment: @ individ 59  I know about the Pell connection with $P=1$ and I have added  such to my answer. Unfortunately, I have inconsistent luck with the ability to change font size in MathJax: Do you know how to make it \small or \footnotesize?

Answer (score -1):

If you solve expression for $n$ you get

$n=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}-a$, let's denote $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$,so we have that $n=b-a$

Now,take look at picture bellow.Note that $AD=a$,and $BD=b-a=n$

If you change value of $b$ and keep $a$ to be constant you will get a infinite number of right triangles,and therefore infinite number of values of $n=b-a$,so answer is yes, there are infinitely many primes $n$ for which equation is solvable.

[image]

Comment: Except that you don't know for which integer values of $b$ yield integer values of $c$.

Comment: @Thomas,That's true,I have answered only on second part of the question...however, one can find one (a,b,n) triple and then for each different triple choose another b such that n becomes prime number

Comment: So, what does your argument say when $n=3$?

Comment: @Thomas,I didn't say that this reasoning is correct for each prime number.I just pointed that there is infinitely many distinct (a,b,n) triples such that n is prime...

Comment: This probably unnecessary at this point but, among primitive Pythagorean triples, the difference between the two legs  is always a prime $P\equiv \pm 1 \mod 8\quad$ and I have shown how to find such triples in my recent answer.

Comment: @poetasis Not quite. Each prime factor of this difference $n$ is $p=\pm1\mod 8$, but $n$ might not be prime. For example, there's $a=24, n=119=7\cdot 17, c=145$ which is primitive.