# nonlinear diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

how to solve a diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ for integers $x,y,z$

i strongly believe there is a geometric solution ,since this is a pythagoras theorem form
or a circle with radius $z$

$x^2+y^2=z^2$

$(\frac{x}{z})^2+(\frac{y}{z})^2=1\implies x=y=\pm z$ or $0$

so we consider a line passing through  points $P_1(- z,0)$ and  $P(x,y)$ both on the circle

$m=\frac{y}{x+z}$

$x^2+m^2(x+z)^2=z^2$

$(m^2+1)x^2+2xzm^2+(m^2-1)z^2=0$

$((m^2+1)x+(m^2-1)z)(x+z)=0$

$\frac{x}{z}=-\frac{m^2-1}{m^2+1}$ or $-1$

let $m=\frac{a}{b}\implies \frac{x}{z}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{b^2+a^2}$

$\frac{y}{z}=\frac{2a^2}{b^2+a^2}$

how to get explicit $z,x,y$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Answer (score 1):

[Euclid's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) says that in essence, $(m^2 - n^2)^2 + (2mn)^2 = (m^2 + n^2)^2$ for all positive integers $m > n$.

This is basically a parametrization of Pythagorean Triplets with two parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot,the links basically assume the solution is already known then show its validity,but i was interested in finding the solution without prior knowledge of Euclid's Formular

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if a conic curve with rational coefficients has one rational point $\rm\:P\:$ then it has infinitely many, since any rational line through $\rm\:P\:$ will intersect the curve in another point, necessarily rational, since if one root of a rational quadratic is rational then so is the other. Therefore, by *sweeping lines* of varying rational slopes through $\rm\:P\:$ we obtain infinitely many rational points on the conic.  Projecting these points onto a line leads to a *rational parametrization* of the conic. For a very nice exposition see Chapter $1$ of Silverman and Tate: *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*. There are also many online expositions, e.g. search on "rational parametrization Pythagorean triple".

For Pythagorean Triples there is even more beautiful geometrical structure. One may generate [Ternary Tree of Pythagorean Triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/k2k12-being-a-perfect-square-for-infinitely-many-k/5567#5567) using arithmetical reflections.