# Find all positive integers n < 200, such that $n^2$ + $(n + 1)^2$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integers n < 200, such that $n^2$ + $(n + 1)^2$  is a perfect square

I tried the following
Let $n^2$ + $(n + 1)^2 = m^2$ where $m$ is a positive integer. Now $$(m+n)(m-n) = (n+1)^2$$ I dont know how to proceed after this. I also tried expanding original equation but that was also of no help.

Comment: Write a programme for them.  That way, you'll know what to look for.

Comment: You could see $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = m^2$ as a quadratic equation of $n$ and solve it.

Comment: $(2n+1)^2-2m^2=-1,$ so this is a case of the negative Pell equation.

Comment: You are talking about Pythagorean triples, which have a known parametrization.  That said, it's such a small sample that routine search is much easier than anything else.

Comment: Specifically, you get $$4n+2=(1+\sqrt 2)^k+(1-\sqrt2)^k$$ when $k$ is odd. Since $-1<1-\sqrt2<0,$ this can be written as $$4n+2=\left\lfloor (1+\sqrt2)^k\right\rfloor$$ for $k$ odd.

Comment: or $n_{j+2}  = 6 n_{j+1}  - n_j   +2 $  with $n_0 = 0, n_1 = 3, n_2 = 20,$

Comment: $$(3,4,5)\\
(20,21,29)\\
(119,120,169)\\
(696,697,985)\\
(4059,4060,5741)\\
(23660,23661,33461)\\
(137903,137904,195025)\\
(803760,803761,1136689)\\
(4684659,4684660,6625109)\\
(27304196,27304197,38613965)\\
(159140519,159140520,225058681)\\
(927538920,927538921,1311738121)\\
(5406093003,5406093004,7645370045)\\
(31509019100,31509019101,44560482149)\\
(183648021599,183648021600,259717522849)\\
(1070379110496,1070379110497,1513744654945)\\
(6238626641379,6238626641380,8822750406821)\\
(36361380737780,36361380737781,51422757785981)$$

Comment: The easiest (and prettiest) way it to use the Pythagorean triple tree as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5567/242).

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Note that $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ has solutions which are Pythagorean triples and these solutions are precisely of the form $(d(u^2-v^2),d(2uv), d(u^2+v^2))$, where $u,v$ are prime to each other (possibly interchanging the X and Y coordinates). If you want only positive integer solutions you can further assume that $u>v$.

For your problem, it follows from the equality $n^2+(n+1)^2=m^2$ that $n,n+1,m$ are pairwise coprime. That means you can find $u,v$ with $u>v$ and $\gcd(u,v)=1$ such that $n=u^2-v^2,~n+1=2uv$ and $m=u^2+v^2$ ($d$ is of course 1 here).